# Dont want to append the duplicate rows in the table using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm getting records dynamically from Database using an Ajax call. But, I want to restrict to add only new rows. For example, if I have rows as follows for 1st ajax call.

```
<tr><td>123</td><td>581</td><td>2013-05-05</td></tr> <br/>
<tr><td>198</td>td>55</td><td>2013-05-05</td></tr>
```

For 2nd ajax call, I'm getting the rows as follows.

```
<tr><td>123</td><td>581</td><td>2013-05-05</td></tr> <br/>
<tr><td>4465</td><td>3481</td>td>2013-06-05</td></tr>
```

Now, I would like to check the table with 1st td value. If the new rows are already having the rows in the table, I don't want to append them. Only the different rows should be appended. In the above example, I dont want to add the td with 123 value, because its already there. I'm confused how to do it.

```
$.ajax({ // Making an Ajax call.
            url:"/Project/getAllMessages.do", // Call URL.
            dataType:"json", // Expecting the data type as Json.                
            data:{ // Pass commodityId,apmcId,mainLabelId & UserDB to the ervice.

                mainLabelId:mainLabelId,
                inputDate:inputDate
            },
            "async":false,
            type:"POST",            
            success:function(allMessagesJson){ // Get Json data in Success Call back function.

                $('#divAllInbox').css('display','none');
                var allMessages = allMessagesJson[0];
                for(index in allMessages){

                    counter ++;
                    arrMsgs[counter] = allMessages[index]; // Take the complete message into Array.     
                    mysqlContentId = allMessages[index].mysqlContentId; //mysqlContentId.                



                    var imgMainLabel = mainLabelName.replace(/\s/g, ""); // Remove spaces from the string.



                    $("#tblMainLabelsInbox tbody").loadTemplate($("#messageTemplate"), // Load All tr's as Template. 
                            {
                                comm_main_labelid:allMessages[index].mainLabelId,
                                comm_mysql_id:mysqlContentId,
                                comm_hidden_date:allMessages[index].date
                            },
                            {
                                append:true
                            }
                    ); // Appended to Table.                        

                } // End For.   



            },
            error:function(xhRequest, ErrorText, thrownError){ // Error Call back function.
                if(xhRequest.status === 401 || xhRequest.status === 403){
                    alert("Bad Request. Please Try Again.");
                } else if ( xhRequest.status === 504 && !ajaxRequest++ ) {
                    loadData(commodity,apmc,mainLabelId,userDB);
                } else if ( xhRequest.status === 500) {
                    alert("Server error. Please try later.");
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: your HTML for your rows is invalid. you should start by fixing that. with regards to getting only new rows, you would want to paginate your results somehow on the backend and return only the data you need. it would be best to put that logic in the backend. searching this site for ajax and paginate keywords should provide you some ideas for that.

Comment: @jammypeach, The HTML Code is edited. I need to validate only on Ajax side. My requirement is such like that.

Comment: you could pass your existing table to your request and build an array with it in php (one tr = one position in array), after select you just look with if in_array.... and if not, add than pass json back and build table new

Comment: @Dwza. I've to check each new record with all of the existing rows in the table. I shouldn't build any new table. I just need to append the unique rows.

Comment: @Nizam was just an option to get a clean and updated table... of course you can run the table with jquery and do some like $.each('tr',tblSelector,function(){ //check row if found break });

Comment: @Dwza. Yes of course. Can you give me an example? I've done it. But, this comment doesn't allow me to give the whole snippet due to length. Where shall I post it?

Comment: @Nizam i guess your loadTemplate is a plugin ??

Comment: there is an answere now... was writing some code but not needed anymore :)

Comment: @Dwza, Yes, loadtemplate is a plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I dont want to add the td with 123 value*

If you're saying that the first column is enough to identify the rows then perhaps as the first line of your `success` handler you could get those values from the table and put them in an array:

```
var rowIds = $("#tblMainLabelsInbox tbody tr td:first-child").map(function() {
                 return $(this).text();
             }).get();
```

...and then within your `for` loop when you need to see if a row just retrieved via Ajax is already in the table just check if it's in the array:

```
if ($.inArray(mysqlContentId, rowIds) === -1) {
    $("#tblMainLabelsInbox tbody").loadTemplate($("#messageTemplate"), 
                        {
                            comm_main_labelid:allMessages[index].mainLabelId,
                            comm_mysql_id:mysqlContentId,
                            comm_hidden_date:allMessages[index].date
                        },
                        {
                            append:true
                        }
     ); // Appended to Table.
     rowIds.push(mysqlContentId);
}
```

I'm assuming in my code above that your `mysqlContentId` variable is the one with the record key id in it. If it is actually `allMessages[index].mainLabelId` then obviously you'd make the appropriate substitution.

I suggest the array because it should be rather more efficient to test for a value in the array on each iteration of your for loop than to test for a value in the DOM. And speaking of efficient, rather than populating the array by looping through the table (with `.map()`) on each Ajax call, perhaps if you simply initialise an empty array when the page first loads:

```
var rowIds = [];
```

...then you can just add the ids during your Ajax processing (as with the `.push()` I showed above) and then you never need to loop through the actual table.

Comment: @Nizam, please consider accepting this answer if it solves your problem, otherwise please post your own solution and accept that as an answer.