# Jquery append new data to old ones has duplicate issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can I add new data to old ones without duplicate my tables?

## logic

1. I select option, data returns in table
2. I select different option, data adds to old ones

## Issue

When I do second part of my logic it add new table as well, **meaning** based on how many times i change my selected option it adds new tables.

## Screenshot

`when i select my first option` having 1 table

[image: one]

`when i select my second option` having 2 tables

[image: two]

### What I want

What I want is when i select my second/third etc. option `image 2`, only have **1** table include data of all those past and current options and not to make 1 table for each of them.

## Code

`HTML`

```
<div class="mt-20 options"></div>
```

`JavaScript`

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('select[name="options"]').on('change', function() {
            var addressID = $(this).val();
            if(addressID) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '{{ url('admin/getoptions') }}/'+encodeURI(addressID),
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success:function(data) {
                        // $('div.options').empty();

                        $('div.options').append('<div class="mb-20"><h4>Check mark your needed options only</h4></div>'+
                          '<table id="table" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive">'+
                          '<thead>'+
                            '<th width="50" class="text-center">Check</th>'+
                            '<th class="text-center">Title</th>'+
                            '<th class="text-center">Price</th>'+
                          '</thead>'+
                          '<tbody></tbody>'+
                          '</table>');

                        // 2. Loop through all entries
                        var keys = ['title'];
                        data.forEach(function(row) {
                          var $row = $('<tr />');

                          $row.append('<td class="text-center" width="50"><label class="switch switch-small"><input type="checkbox" /><span><input class="form-control" type="text" name="optionID[]" value="'+row['id']+'"></span></label></td>');
                          keys.forEach(function(key) {
                            $row.append('<td>' + row[key] + '</td>');
                          });
                          $row.append('<td class="text-center"><input class="form-control" placeholder="if fill this price, the price will add to product price when user select it." type="number" name="optionPRICE[]"></td>');

                          $('#table tbody').append($row);
                        });
                    }
                });
            }else{
                $('div.options').empty();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Post your HTML also

Comment: @AshayMandwarya updated, all happens in append html is only a div tag

Comment: Well, doesn't the `append` argument show that you willingly add a `table`? If you don't want that, then why do you do it there?

Comment: If you don't want a table for every option, just remove the `<table>` element from the HTML you append...? Create a static table which all rows get appended to.

Comment: @trincot the thing is i don't want to have empty table in my view before selecting any option thats why i load table structure in append.

Comment: In that case hide it with CSS, and unhide it once it is populated. See my answer for the 3 steps to take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps to take:

1. Remove the `$('div.options').append( ... )` call
2. Add the following HTML to your static `div` element, and hide it with `style="display:none"`:

   ```
   <div class="mt-20 options" style="display:none">
       <div class="mb-20"><h4>Check mark your needed options only</h4></div>
       <table id="table" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive">
           <thead>
               <th width="50" class="text-center">Check</th>
               <th class="text-center">Title</th>
               <th class="text-center">Price</th>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
           </tbody>
       </table>
   </div>
   ```
3. Add code after the `data.forEach` loop, to unhide the `div`:

   ```
       $('#table tbody').append($row);
   }); // end of loop
   $("div.options").show();  // <---
   ```

Comment: this actually works, just a tiny issue in appending. imagine i select option `color` data appends then i select option `size` data appends `so far so good`, but if again i select `color` by mistake or not. it shows color data again, this basically no have issue till the moment that i want to send those data in backend, that time filtering same id's is hard. is there anyway we avoid this duplicated appends?

Comment: Sure: you should then keep a global variable containing the *keys* of what should be unique. You can use a plain object (like `var keys = {}`) and add as property (`keys[row[key]] = 1`) as you go. When `row[key] in keys` then you *don't* add the row. NB: this really is a different question though.

Comment: if you think this issue isn't relevant to this question i can make new question, would you then help fixing this? or you can just help me here for it?

Comment: A new question would be appropriate, and chances are that someone else will answer it within minutes. Just do us one favour: first search on this site if a similar question has not been asked before.

Comment: thank you, it is probably been asked during the time, thing is finding same issue and similar issue is different :).  anyway i will share the link here for you in case you're interested to help. Thank you.

Comment: This could be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20742775/dont-want-to-append-the-duplicate-rows-in-the-table-using-jquery although the answer is not really that good :/ I could not really find a good answer to similar questions, so I would say: ... go for it.

Comment: thank you, but i didn't understand a thing of it :))) i'm not good at this j langs :)))  here is another one i made maybe you like to see? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54159941/avoiding-duplicated-data-in-same-table-with-jquery

Answer (score 1):

First you need to build your table once. But you are appending new tables every success call. That happens in the line:

```
$('div.options').append('<div class="mb-20">...
```

That append is actually creating the table and appending it to the div.

Instead you should create the table only one time before the success callback, then just update it with the new data.

```js
$(function(){
    var updateTable =  function() {
        var addressID = $(this).val();
        var data = JSON.parse(addressID);
        
        // show the table div
        $('div.options').show();

        // clear old rows
        $('tbody', myTable).empty();

        // 2. Loop through all entries
        var keys = ['title'];
        data.forEach(function(row) {
          var $row = $('<tr />');
          $row.append('<td class="text-center" width="50"><label class="switch switch-small"><input type="checkbox" /><span><input class="form-control" type="text" name="optionID[]" value="'+row+'"></span></label></td>');

          keys.forEach(function(key) {
            $row.append('<td>' + row[key] + '</td>');
          });
          $row.append('<td class="text-center"><input class="form-control" placeholder="if fill this price, the price will add to product price when user select it." type="number" name="optionPRICE[]"></td>');

          $('tbody', myTable).append($row);
        });
    };
    
    // create and save table for later manipulations
    var myTable = $('<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive">'+
                      '<thead>'+
                        '<th width="50" class="text-center">Check</th>'+
                        '<th class="text-center">Title</th>'+
                        '<th class="text-center">Price</th>'+
                      '</thead>'+
                      '<tbody></tbody>'+
                      '</table>');
   // append h4
   $('div.options').append('<div class="mb-20"><h4>Check mark your needed options only</h4></div>');
   // append the table
   $('div.options').append(myTable);
   // select event
   $('select[name="options"]').on('change', updateTable);
   updateTable.call($('select[name="options"]').first());
});
```

```css
{"d":4,"e":5,"f": 6}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="options">
  <option value="[1,2,3]">Data1</option>
  <option value="[4,5,6]">Data2</option>
</select>
<div class="options"></div>
```

Comment: no this shows empty table in my view before i select any option, also refresh data when i select another option

Comment: same as before.

Comment: you replaced the whole script? did you get any errors? is there any special css for the #table id?

Comment: yes i replaced all script, no error data appends in view just not the way thy supposed to (i explained in first comment for you)

Comment: I did a snippet to show exactly how to to it and that it works. I removed the ajax call to avoid CORS problems, but the table update still has the same logic.

Comment: i guess that was the issue `$('tbody', myTable).empty();` i didn't want to remove old ones i just wanted to add new ones and in the same table.

Comment: anyway it solved now thank you so much, i will vote-up your answer. and i have new one related to this question maybe you can help there as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54159941/avoiding-duplicated-data-in-same-table-with-jquery

Comment: great! hope you can solve all your issues and good luck! gonna check on that other question later. cya