# Avoiding duplicated data in same table with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a table which the data of it will append based on selecting options, the issue is i want to avoid appending data multiple times.

Imagine i select option `color` data appends then I select option `size` data appends as well **so far so good**.

But if again I select `color` by *mistake or not*. It shows color data again, this basically no have issue till the moment that I want to send those data in back-end, that time filtering same id's with different values is hard.

## Question is

Is there anyway to avoid this duplicated appends? So when I select `color` once data show only once and second time not show?

## Code

`HTML`

```
<div class="mt-20 options" style="display:none">
    <div class="mb-20"><h4>Check mark your needed options only</h4></div>
    <table id="table" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive">
        <thead>
            <th width="50" class="text-center">Check</th>
            <th class="text-center">Title</th>
            <th class="text-center">Price</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

`JavaScript`

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('select[name="options"]').on('change', function() {
            var addressID = $(this).val();
            if(addressID) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '{{ url('admin/getoptions') }}/'+encodeURI(addressID),
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success:function(data) {
                        // $('div.options').empty();



                        // 2. Loop through all entries
                        var keys = ['title'];
                        data.forEach(function(row) {
                          var $row = $('<tr />');

                          $row.append('<td class="text-center" width="50"><label class="switch switch-small"><input type="checkbox" /><span><input class="form-control" type="text" name="optionID[]" value="'+row['id']+'"></span></label></td>');
                          keys.forEach(function(key) {
                            $row.append('<td>' + row[key] + '</td>');
                          });
                          $row.append('<td class="text-center"><input class="form-control" placeholder="if fill this price, the price will add to product price when user select it." type="number" name="optionPRICE[]"></td>');

                          $('#table tbody').append($row);
                        });
                        $("div.options").show();
                    }
                });
            }else{
                $('div.options').empty();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Any idea on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course. You can create an array which is empty at the start:

```
var addresses = [];
```

whenever you have requested for an address, store it inside the array, like

```
addresses.push(addressID);
```

and change the if to check whether `addressID` is truey and not yet requested, like:

```
if (addressID && (addresses.indexOf(addressID) < 0)) {
```

Full code:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        var addresses = [];
        $('select[name="options"]').on('change', function() {
            var addressID = $(this).val();
            if (addresses.indexOf(addressID) < 0) {
            if(addressID) {
                addresses.push(addressID);
                $.ajax({
                    url: '{{ url('admin/getoptions') }}/'+encodeURI(addressID),
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success:function(data) {
                        // $('div.options').empty();



                        // 2. Loop through all entries
                        var keys = ['title'];
                        data.forEach(function(row) {
                          var $row = $('<tr />');

                          $row.append('<td class="text-center" width="50"><label class="switch switch-small"><input type="checkbox" /><span><input class="form-control" type="text" name="optionID[]" value="'+row['id']+'"></span></label></td>');
                          keys.forEach(function(key) {
                            $row.append('<td>' + row[key] + '</td>');
                          });
                          $row.append('<td class="text-center"><input class="form-control" placeholder="if fill this price, the price will add to product price when user select it." type="number" name="optionPRICE[]"></td>');

                          $('#table tbody').append($row);
                        });
                        $("div.options").show();
                    }
                });
            }else{
                $('div.options').empty();
            }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, i will test this and let you know.

Comment: @mafortis you are welcome, please let me know about the results.

Comment: I've tried your code, when i select same option for the second time it removes all the appends. maybe just showing alert be better option rather than cleaning appends. any idea?

Comment: @mafortis sorry about that, I did not notice the else there. I have wrapped that part of code into an outer if. Please check the code in my edited answer.

Comment: it seems to working just fine, however i tried to add alert and added else for `if (addresses.indexOf(addressID) < 0) {` it starts to act weird then i just removed it :) as that alert part wasn't in my question just ignore it :D thanks for the help appreciate it.